# Remote calling an ejb method with an abstract parameter

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

Remote calling an ejb method with a parameter extended on client results with ClassNotFoundException.

For example:

```
@Stateless
public class EjbService implements EjbServiceRemote {
    public void doSth(SomeAbstractClass sac) {
        //do sth with sac
    }
}

@Remote
public interface EjbServiceRemote {
    public void doSth(SomeAbstractClass sac);
}

package com.simple;
public class SimpleEJBTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        EjbServiceRemote ejbRemote = //lookup stuff

        SomeAbstractClass sac = new SomeAbstractClass {}; //extend it

        ejbRemote.doSth(sac); //results in ClassNotFound
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet SimpleEJBTestServlet threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014154: Failed to marshal EJB parameters
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simple.SimpleEJBTestServlet$1 from [Module "deployment.simpleEjbService.ear.simpleEjb:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

SomeAbstractClass is in classpath of client and remote apps but they are loaded with different classloaders(obviously).

Is this behavior expected or am I missing something? How do I solve this case?

Answer (score 2):

> `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simple.SimpleEJBTestServlet$1`

The anonymous implementation class `SimpleEJBTestServlet$1` is only known to the server but not to the client.

All parameter, return and exceptions types have to be known to both parties. It's not possible to serialize something the other party does not know (this includes subclasses), as with Reomte EJBs only the content (objects) get serialized, not the classes themselves.

I recommend to keep them in a separate JAR, which you can share between client and server projects.

Comment: But the "thing" I'm sending by serializing is SomeAbstractClass and it's in the classpath of both remote and client apps. Why does it matter how I extend or implement it on client?

Comment: No, you're sending an object which has a concrete, dynamic type (dynamic <-> static typing). What would you expect that the runtime, dynamic type of the object at the client side should be? An object cannot have an abstract type...

Comment: Then it means either: 1) I can't use interfaces or abstract classes as ejb method parameters or 2) I have to share client implementation details with remote app, which has nothing to do with them

Comment: It's absolutely fine to specify your remote methods with interface and abstract classes parameters. But both parties have to know all implementation classes of which objects are exchanged between them. I recommend 3) to keep these implementation classes free from client/ server side code.

Comment: In my case, SomeAbstractClass is extended with some JSF specific attributes (like SelectItem etc.) that would mean putting JSF classes into remote app's classpath, which does not have anything to do with JSF.

Comment: I recommend to do some refactorings so that your DTOs don't have dependencies to JSF.

Comment: DTO's are abstract and don't have dependency on JSF but client is extending and making them depend on JSF, then sending them as original DTO's...

Comment: @Reek again: This includes also subclasses. I recommend to refactor them and get rid of the JSF dependencies in any object you want to serialize between client and server.